# Classifying the Class Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

My goal is to determine the ideal class group of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-39}]$.

Here is what I have done:

(i) $-39 \equiv1 \bmod 4$ and so the ring of integers is $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-x+10) = \mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2}]$.

(ii) 2 and 3 are not prime in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2}]$ and

(iii) $(2) = (2, \frac{5+\sqrt{-39}}{2})(2, \frac{5-\sqrt{-39}}{2})$ and $$(3) = (3, \frac{3+\sqrt{-39}}{2})(3, \frac{3-\sqrt{-39}}{2})= (3, \frac{3+\sqrt{-39}}{2})^2.$$

Are these steps correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $$\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+10)/(2)=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-x)=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/( x(x-1))$$ has two distinct maximal ideals $(x),(x-1)$ thus $\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2}]$ has two maximal ideals above $2$  : $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2})$ and $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2}-1)$

$2$ is a unit modulo $3$ so $(3) = (3,\sqrt{-39})^2$ is equivalent to what you wrote